# wp_list_pages not outputting in variable

Tags: php, wordpress

In attempting to produce what you would have thought would be a simple task of a secondary menu in Wordpress, I have come up with the code below in my theme:

```
<?php   // Show parent's children if on child page
        if ($post->post_parent) {
            $children = wp_list_pages('sort_column=menu_order&title_li=&child_of='.$post->post_parent);
            if ($children) {
                echo '<ul>'.$children.'</ul>';
            }
        }
        // Show children if they exist
        else { 
            $children = wp_list_pages('sort_column=menu_order&title_li=&child_of='.$post->ID);
            if ($children) {
                echo '<ul>'.$children.'</ul>';
            }
        }?>
```

It is working fine, except the `<ul></ul>` isn't appearing. If I delete the if/else statements, I get exactly the same result. It's as if it's producing the result instead of storing it in the $children variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `&echo=0` to the wp_list_pages function else it goes echoes the pages out.

More info on the codex.

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_list_pages